# Sqlcmd: 'KReadOnly': Unknown Option

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sqlcmd, listener

I am using SQL Server 2014 SP2 with AG, running this command:

```
sqlcmd -S ABC-ISELL -E -d ABP_SFA_BMB -K ReadOnly
```

Where `ABC-ISELL` is the listener name, I am getting this error:

```
Sqlcmd: 'KReadOnly': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help.
```

`sqlcmd -?` shows there is no `-K` option, it`s just this:

```
[-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

One needs to use recent enough a version of `sqlcmd`. The parameter for application intent is `-K`. Note that sqlcmd's parameters are case sensitive, which is uncommon in Windows environment.

To check sqlcmd's version, run it with `-?` parameter. Like so,

```
C:\>sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 14.0.1000.169 NT
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

usage: Sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
...
[-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
...
-K application intent
```

For updated version, check Microsoft's [product documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017), 
 there's a link to [Download center](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=825643).

Comment: That instance was SQL 2008 R2 upgraded to 2014 SP2, database version now is: 12.0.5571, still showing this!!

C:\Windows\system32>sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 10.50.6000.34 NT x64

Which is weird!

Answer (score 0):

That instance was SQL 2008 R2 upgraded to 2014 SP2, database version now is: 12.0.5571, still showing this!!

C:\Windows\system32>sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 10.50.6000.34 NT x64

I already restarted the service & rebooted the server, same issue.

Also installed Command Line Utilities 14.0 for SQL Server, same issue.

Which is weird! Any advise?

Comment: Looks like the old version is in path before the new one. Look in location like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn` for the new version.